# list items or tables?

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-lists

I am in the process of creating two columns.  In the first column will be a picture and in the second column will be a number associated with how many times the picture is clicked(basically).  So I need the two to line up, but I also want the images to line up with one another as well as the number to line up with one another.  So my questions is is it better to do this in a table or to create two divs, put the list items in each div and then float them left next to one another?

If there is a better way I am open.

Option 1

```
<div>
    <div style="float:left">
        <ul>
            <li><img></li>
            <li><img></li>
            <li><img></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left">
        <ul>
            <li><value></li>
            <li><value></li>
            <li><value></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Option 2

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td><img></td>
       <td><value></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><img></td>
       <td><value></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><img></td>
       <td><value></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am sure there is a better way of doing this.  I think these both would work, but it seems like there should be something better.  Especially because I will have to so a bunch of CSS to line them all up and make them functionable.

Final result:
CSS

```
img{
float:left;
clear:left;
}

 span{
  clear:right;
  float:right;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><img /><span>value</span></li>
<li><img /><span>value</span></li>
<li><img /><span>value</span></li>
    <li><img /><span>value</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep just one list with the images and values in the same list item, ie:

```
<li><img /><span>value</span></li>
<li><img /><span>value</span></li>
<li><img /><span>value</span></li>
```

This way the value will always be alongside the image, and can be styled directly using the span.

A table shouldn't be used for this. If the above method is unsuitable I can write you some jquery to line up two lists, but it would be much neater to use the above method imo.

Answer (score -1):

Use the table. It is simpler to understand and maintain. Makes it easier to vertically align items if you images are of varing heights.

Comment: downvoter please comment? What is wrong with a table in this situation?